# Angular Promise catch block error object is empty/null

Tags: javascript, angularjs

```
function serviceCall() {
var defer =$q.defer();
// make http request
return defer.promise;
}

serviceCall().then(function(){
}).catch(function(err){
//log err
})
```

If the service is failing I am getting proper status code such as 404
but there are cases when the err object itself is null

when will an error object be null?

Comment: do you mind creating a plunker?

Comment: It could be that its the server that is not returning a correct response, when you get a null error. Please inspect the response in your browsers Web Console (f12).

Comment: Can you add in the service request? You need a defer.resolve() or defer.reject() in there in order to return something.

Answer (score 0):

Service

```
this.getData=function(){
    var deferred = $q.defer();
    $http({method:'GET', url:'app/rest/data'})
    .success(function(data,status,header,config){
        deferred.resolve(data);
    })
    .error(function(data,status,header,config){
        deferred.reject(status);
    })
    return deferred.promise;
};
```

Function in controller

```
    myService.getData().then(function(data){
        $scope.myData = data;
    },function(reason){
        $scope.errorMessage = reason;
    });
```

From server side error message should come, if length of `reason` in zero then u can write your own error message as follows

```
    myService.getData().then(function(data){
        $scope.myData = data;
    },function(reason){
       if(reason.length <1){
          $scope.errorMessage = "Something wrong happned";  
       } else {
        $scope.errorMessage = reason;
       }
    });
```

Comment: I am checking and logging if the reason is null ,what i want to know why the  reason can be null ideally if there is a failure something should come as a reason

Comment: That you can not handle at your end, the error reason should come from server side. You can only show errors depends upon server's response i.e. 200, 400, 401, 402, 403, 500 etc etc